# Maple calls absolute convergent sum divergent, but why?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, maple

> Determine whether the sum
>
> [image]
>
> is divergent, absolute convergent or conditionally convergent.

First, I tried to solve this by hand. I tried to find a convergent majorant series for the series in question.

$$\bigg|\cos(n^2+1) \frac{2+n^2}{1+n!} \bigg| \leq\frac{n^2}{n!}$$

It turns out that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}=2e$, according to Maple that is. This result shows that the sum in the question is absolute convergent.

I also tried to use Maple to double check my answer, and it gave me this.

[image]

When Maple gives this sort of output, it usually means that the sum is not convergent. But didn't I just show that it was, or have I made a mistake?

Can a "Maple man" tell me why Maple gives this result, and perhaps how I can avoid it?

Comment: The series does converge, but only a maple person can tell you why maple doesn't recognize it as such.  Can you use maple to make a table of partial sums for some large values of n?

Comment: It will be related to the `formal=false` parameter, without it I get it is approximately `-1.379777889`

Answer (score 4):

The sum converges absolutly. Your proof is correct (exept that inequlity $\frac{n^2+2}{1+n!} \leq \frac{n^2}{n!}$ is not true, but the last fraction may be replaced by $\frac{2+n^2}{n!}$, which give us convergent series).

Answer (score 0):

As it was already mentioned by Timur B., your proof is correct except a moment $\bigg|\cos(n^2+1) \frac{2+n^2}{1+n!} \bigg| \leq\frac{2+n^2}{n!}$ instead of $\frac{n^2}{n!}$.

I will add that if we see that we shouldn't trust to Maple, so it's better not to use Maple to find  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}=2e$ in order to finish the proof)
Although this time the statement is correct and indeed $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}=2e$,

it's easier to notice that for $n > 100$ we have $\bigg|\cos(n^2+1) \frac{2+n^2}{1+n!} \bigg| \leq\frac{2+n^2}{n!} \le \frac{2n^2}{100 n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)} <$$
$$ < \frac{2n^2}{100n \cdot \frac{n}2 \cdot \frac{n}2 \cdot \frac{n}2} \le \frac{1}{n^2} \le \frac{1}{n(n-1) } = \frac1{n-1} - \frac{1}n,$
and the series $\sum_{n \ge 100} ( \frac1{n-1} - \frac{1}n ) = (\frac{1}{99} - \frac{1}{100}) + (\frac{1}{100} - \frac{1}{101}) + \ldots ... $ converges (to $\frac{1}{99}$) obviously.